# can't seem to create new table in sqlite android

Tags: android

i have come into quite a funny hole here. i can't seem to be able to create a 2nd database table to my existing one. i basically want them to be of the same structure and the same of columns, in other words a copy of my existing table. my goal is to copy the values from my first table to the second table. The first table i created works cos i have used it already.

i have tried everything i know, unistalled and reinstalled the app to clear the database, changed the name of the tables, version..etc  but i keep getting a "table not found exception". please any ideas what could be causing this and how to go about it?.. thanks

here is the creation for both of them:

```
/* tables variable*/
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Memo";
    public static final String ROUTE = "Route";

 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String NAME = "Title";
public static final String DATE = "date";
public static final String TIME = "time";
public static final String VENUE = "venue";
public static final String CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String PRIORITY = "priority";
    public static final String NOTES = "notes";

  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table Memo (_id integer primary key autoincrement," 
    + "Title text, date text, time text,"
    + "venue text, category text,"
     + "priority text, notes text);";

  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ROUTE = "create table Route (_id integer primary key autoincrement," 
    + "Title text, date text, time text,"
    + "venue text, category text,"
     + "priority text, notes text);";


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "created Memo table");

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_ROUTE );
        Log.d(TAG, "created Route table");

    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG,"upgrading Database from version"+ oldVersion+ "to"
                +newVersion+ "which old data will be lost");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS Memo");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS Route");

        onCreate(db);
    }
}


public void copyData(long rowId){

db.execSQL("insert into ROUTE select * from DATABASE_TABLE WHERE KEY_ID = rowId");
}
```

Logcat Exception is:

```
10-22 15:47:17.326: ERROR/Database(807): Failure 1 (no such table: ROUTE) on 0x1d7f20 when preparing 'insert into ROUTE select * from DATABASE_TABLE WHERE KEY_ID = rowId'.

10-22 15:47:17.356: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

10-22 15:47:17.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ROUTE: insert into ROUTE select * from DATABASE_TABLE WHERE KEY_ID = rowId

10-22 15:47:17.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)

10-22 15:47:17.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1496)

10-22 15:47:17.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at com.MemoManager.DBAdapter.copyData(DBAdapter.java:265)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be referring to your DATABASE_TABLE in the insert string? I assume it needs to be 
"insert into ROUTE select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE KEY_ID = rowId"

EDIT: I think Aaron might correct too/instead.

Comment: well am not sure.. will give it a try, but i would have thought it would refer to a "syntax error" more of, than a "table not found exception" and besides, it explicitly says "ROUTE" in the exception.

Comment: @sparrow then I'm probably wrong, and Aaron is most likely correct.

Comment: Also ROUTE is being referred to in the string. Should be: "insert into " + ROUTE + " select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE KEY_ID = rowId". And is KEY_ID the proper column name? It looks like you called it "_id". Not sure if SQLite appends something or not. But you  definitely have to refer to column and table names in the proper case here.

Comment: well.. you might have a point there. because i created static constants for that, but i would have thought it gets used in both cases. will add it now. and yeah, i have that syntax error corrected in the method, its still the same. i would edit my question to include the constants i have there. don't know what else to do  :(

Comment: Am trying not to make the code too long, so it doesn't become distressful for you guys. thats why i try to keep it short as possible.

Comment: Yeah, raybritton is right too I think. You should have: db.execSQL("insert into ROUTE select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE KEY_ID = rowId"); -- Could it also be that ROUTE is case sensitive? Sqlite on my machine isn't, but I don't know about your platform, you're creating table "Route" but referencing "ROUTE"...

Comment: hmmm.. never heard about sql being case sensitive on different platform.. well am not too experienced with it anyway. will try what you suggested but i felt it would give a syntax error if that was the case.

Comment: hmmm.. funny, its now giving me a: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_ID: insert into ROUTE select * from Memo WHERE KEY_ID = rowId"
but as i say, the first row is working. or does that mean i have to use a different KEY_ID for the 2nd database table?..

Comment: i don't know why its giving an exception " no such column: KEY_ID" because i am already using the first database table and its working. yeah, i know this is tiresome, am sorry about that. but anyone have a link i can check or something?.. thanks

Comment: Because there is no KEY_ID column, you have the columns: _id, Title, date, time, venue, category, priority, and notes

Comment: oh gosh am sorry about this.. Thanks! i did something earlier and did not realise about that. it works now! Thank you guys very much for all the input!. seems i have to brush up on my sql, but first, i need some sleep!!  have a great weekend.  :)

Comment: oh.. sorry about that. will do it now

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a paren in your DATABASE_CREATE and DATABASE_CREATE_ROUTE

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table Memo (_id integer primary key autoincrement," 
    + "Title text, date text, time text,"
    + "venue text, category text,"
    + "priority text, notes text;";
                                ^ (HERE?)
```

Comment: oh sorry about that. its not the problem. i had it in my code, i did not realise i did not copy it when i was posting the question.

Comment: Mind to post the logcat log of that exception?

Comment: and i can't think of anything else. i don't know what else i can chage. since i have tried the changing the names and version. i once read somewhere in a post about the problem linking to the onUpgrade() method in the sqlite database, but sadly no solution was shown. does anybody know anything about that please? i have added how i did my onUpgrade method.